# How to expose spring tag lib to Freemaker configuration using java and to process Freemarker Template class?

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker, spring-java-config

I have been trying to use freemarker.template.Template class to process  a given .ftl template. Basiclaly it is not finding the spring tag libs and fails when it encounters the first <@spring.url.../> tag. However, it reads spring macro directives just fine.

Attaching my freemarker config in spring and the error message:

I am using spring 4, with freemarker 2.3.23. While running my Spring MVC application on tomcat 7, it complains about following:

> ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
>     - Failed at: @spring.url "/imports/app/vendor/boot...  [in template "config/pages/default-page.ftl" at line 5, column 54]
>   ----] with root cause FreeMarker template error: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
>   ==> spring  [in template "config/pages/default-page.ftl" at line 5, column 56]
>
> Java stack trace (for programmers):
>   ---- freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...]     at
>   freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException.getInstance(InvalidReferenceException.java:131)
>     at
>   freemarker.core.UnexpectedTypeException.newDesciptionBuilder(UnexpectedTypeException.java:77)
>     at
>   freemarker.core.UnexpectedTypeException.(UnexpectedTypeException.java:40)
>     at freemarker.core.NonHashException.(NonHashException.java:46)
>     at freemarker.core.Dot._eval(Dot.java:45)   at
>   freemarker.core.Expression.eval(Expression.java:78)   at
>   freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:74)   at
>   freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)   at
>   freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)     at
>   freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)   at
>   freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:302)     at
>   freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:325)   at
>   com.isys.ghp.server.services.web.impls.HtmlRenditionComposer.composeRendition(HtmlRenditionComposer.java:43)
>     at
>   com.isys.ghp.controllers.app.RootControllerApp.welcome(RootControllerApp.java:48)
>     at
>   com.isys.ghp.controllers.app.RootControllerApp$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cebaa583.invoke()
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
>     at
>   com.isys.ghp.server.aspects.MethodLogger.around(MethodLogger.java:21)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
>     at
>   com.isys.ghp.controllers.app.RootControllerApp$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$55180b14.welcome()
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Code of MVCConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

```
@Bean 
public FreeMarkerViewResolver freemarkerViewResolver() {
    LOGGER.debug("Executing freemarkerViewResolver()");
    FreeMarkerViewResolver resolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
    resolver.setExposeSpringMacroHelpers(true);  
    resolver.setExposeRequestAttributes(true);
    resolver.setCache(true); 
    resolver.setPrefix(""); 
    resolver.setSuffix(".ftl");
    return resolver; 
}

@Bean(name="fmAdvanceConfigFactoryBean")    
public FreeMarkerConfigurer getFreemarkerConfig() throws IOException, TemplateException  {
    FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean freeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean = new FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean();
    FreeMarkerConfigurer result = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
    result.setTemplateLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/views");
    result.setConfiguration(freeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean.createConfiguration());
    return result;
}
```

> Template processing block:

```
Template pageHTML = fmAdvanceConfigFactoryBean.getTemplate("config/pages/default-page.ftl");  
StringWriter pageWriter = new StringWriter();
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
pageHTML.process(map, pageWriter);
```

I have been looking a lot of pages providing advance configuration but none of them is able to resolve this. I am not sure what I am missing here. Any help will be useful and appreciated!

Thanks!

Update: You were right, ddekany! Like you suggested, there was another method in different config file. I have commented that method and checked there is no other point of call. However, now its complaining about not finding the template. See my answer below. You were right. There was another method in different config file. I have commented that method and checked there is no other point of call. However, now its complaining about not finding the template:

> freemarker.template.TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found for
>   name "/config/pages/default-page.ftl". The name was interpreted by
>   this TemplateLoader:
>   LegacyDefaultFileTemplateLoader(baseDir="/Users/mdani/Data_MD/Developer_MD/Workspace/Tools/GH-Platform/STS.app/Contents/MacOS",
>   canonicalBasePath="/Users/mdani/Data_MD/Developer_MD/Workspace/Tools/GH-Platform/STS.app/Contents/MacOS/").
>   Warning: The "template_loader" FreeMarker setting wasn't set
>   (Configuration.setTemplateLoader), and using the default value is most
>   certainly not intended and dangerous, and can be the cause of this
>   error.    at
>   freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:2701)
>     at
>   freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:2503)

Simplified class:

```
    @Loggable
@Bean(name="fmAdvanceConfigFactoryBean")    
public FreeMarkerConfigurer getFreemarkerConfig() throws IOException, TemplateException  {
    Properties settings = new Properties(); 
    settings.setProperty("auto_import", "/spring.ftl as spring");
    FreeMarkerConfigurer result = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
    result.setTemplateLoaderPaths("/WEB-INF/views","classpath:/");
    result.setFreemarkerSettings(settings);
    return result;
}
```

New Error:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with
>   path [/GHPWebApp] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested
>   exception is freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following
>   has evaluated to null or missing:
>   ==> springMacroRequestContext  [in template "spring.ftl" at line 89, column 134]
>
> ---- Tip: If the failing expression is known to legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default
>   value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if
>   myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing. (These only
>   cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression,
>
> ### use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??
>
> ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
>     - Failed at: ${springMacroRequestContext.getContex...  [in template "spring.ftl" in macro "url" at line 89, column 132]
>     - Reached through: @spring.url "/imports/app/vendor/boot...  [in template "config/pages/default-page.ftl" at line 4, column 54]
>   ----] with root cause FreeMarker template error: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
>   ==> springMacroRequestContext  [in template "spring.ftl" at line 89, column 134]
>
> ---- Tip: If the failing expression is known to legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default
>   value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if
>   myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing. (These only
>   cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression,
>
> ### use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??
>
> ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
>     - Failed at: ${springMacroRequestContext.getContex...  [in template "spring.ftl" in macro "url" at line 89, column 132]
>
> ### - Reached through: @spring.url "/imports/app/vendor/boot...  [in template "config/pages/default-page.ftl" at line 4, column 54]
>
> Java stack trace (for programmers):
>   ---- freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...]     at
>   freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException.getInstance(InvalidReferenceException.java:134)
>     at
>   freemarker.core.UnexpectedTypeException.newDesciptionBuilder(UnexpectedTypeException.java:85)
>     at
>   freemarker.core.UnexpectedTypeException.(UnexpectedTypeException.java:48)
>     at freemarker.core.NonHashException.(NonHashException.java:49)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the `spring` variable is missing because your template doesn't start with `<#import "/spring.ftl" as spring>`, nor you have configured an auto-import for that. The last is the more convenient way. Something like `Properties settings = new Properties(); settings.setProperty("auto_import", "/spring.ftl as spring"); configurer.setFreemarkerSettings(settings);`.

(BTW, upgrade FreeMarker to the latest 2.x.x... 2.3.23 is old.)

Comment: Hi ddekany, Thanks for a quick response. I have upgraded the dependency to 2.3.26-incubating, and tried the auto_import too. It still gives the same exception - it finds spring variable null!                                                      
The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> spring  [in template "config/pages/default-page.ftl" at line 5, column 56] Any further thoughts?

Comment: That means that the auto-import wasn't even attempted. (If it's attempted and it doesn't find the file, then the template fails at the auto-import, not later.) Maybe `setFreemarkerSettings` is called somewhere else as well, and replaces your value. You could override the `postProcessConfiguration(Configuration config)` method to log what `config.getAutoImports()` returns.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the issue, but the latest version is 2.3.27-incubating, not 2.3.26-incubating.

Comment: You were right. There was another method in different config file. I have commented that method and checked there is no other point of call. However, now its complaining about not finding the template. See my answer below. You were right. There was another method in different config file. I have commented that method and checked there is no other point of call. However, now its complaining about not finding the template. Kindly see my update above in question!

Comment: I have changed it to latest - 2.3.27-incubating :)

Comment: While setting up something with pure FreeMarker API is straightforward (though even there, you first set `setClassForTemplateLoading` and then `setServletContextForTemplateLoading`, which will just overwrite the earlier), instead try to use the `FreeMarkerConfigurer` API where you can, because that also uses the FreeMarker API directly, and you are interfering with it. There's `FreeMarkerConfigurer.setTemplateLoaderPaths` and `setTemplateLoaders`. Also note that the `TemplateLoader` needed to find `spring.ftl` is added by `FreeMarkerConfigurer` automatically; you don't have to deal with that.

Comment: Also, there's something really off there, as you end up with a `Configuration` without the `TemplateLoader` set (as the error message says). While your code is wrong on other ways, it would produce a different error message. So it's as if you are using a different `Configuration` instance, where the `templateLoader` setting was never set, or if something somewhere explicitly resets that setting to its default value.

Comment: What you are saying make sense. I have simplified my version, however now its failing inside spring.ftl - Failed at: ${springMacroRequestContext.getContex..., springMacroRequestContext being null.

Comment: Thanks for helping me realise the mistake and your guidance till here. So, I have injected "springMacroRequestContext" as a request attribute as part of my template model, and it seems to be working..! However, I am wondering why "springMacroRequestContext" needs to be set explicitly, even in ViewResolver?

Comment: Certainly because you don't let Spring to call the template, and so it has no opportunity to smuggle in `springMacroRequestContext`. Normally, you return a `ViewAndModel` in your controller, and Spring does the rest. But you call `Template.process` directly, hence specifying the data-model directly to FreeMarker.

Comment: Yup, I follow you!

Comment: One more which I don't understand. Earlier I had <#assign form=JspTaglibs["http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"] /> in one of my ftl. Now, Template.process would not process it. What is the correct way to expose this using the setup above? Should I use auto_import for this too? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `JspTaglibs` is not an import, but a variable that's added by `freemarker.ext.servlet.FreemarkerServlet` (see source code). Frameworks that don't use `FreemarkerServlet` may replicate that feature, but as far as I know Spring MVC has no out-of-the-box support for that. `FreemarkerServlet` was introduced (some 15 years ago or so) to help migration from JSP Model-2 applications to FreeMarker, but modern frameworks often don't rely on that model anymore, and thus nor on `FreemarkerServlet`.